# How to add an active class when a specific link has been clicked using bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a class to a clicked nav menu li using bootstrap and jquery.
When I click on a menu the class is added as expected, but not the related css property - in the specific case the colour red -
Below you can find a very simple example.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navlist a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#navlist a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });

  });
```

```css
.nav {
  color: green;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="navlist">
  <li id="home"><a class="nav" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li id="about"><a class="nav" href="#">About Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jobgaraux/yLpn2nmb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $('#navlist a').click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $('#navlist a').removeClass('active');
              $('#navlist a').addClass('nav');
              $(this).toggleClass('nav');
              $(this).toggleClass('active');
          });
});
```

and this CSS -

```
a.nav:link { color: green; }
a.active:link { color: red; }
```

Here is fiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/yLpn2nmb/3/

Comment: Hi sid, your suggestion works perfectly. Thanks anyway to all.

Answer (score 3):

It could be another style, such as `#navlist a { color: #000; }` elsewhere is your code that is overriding your `.active` class:

Try changing:

```
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

To:

```
#navlist a.active {
    color: red;
}
```

Or:

```
#navlist a.nav.active {
    color: red;
}
```

This will increase the [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) of the class, which should override any other class that could be overriding it.

NOTE: You say the actual jQuery is working as expected so I've focused purely on the CSS aspect of your question...

Comment: It is the `a:focus, a:hover {color: #23527c; text-decoration: underline;}`  rule from bootstrap overriding his CSS. his CSS gets applied when the focus it lost

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

});
```

I think that is what you want to happen